# Error in installation and loading of the "scales" packages in R studio server version 1.0.153

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, rstudio-server

I am using R Studio Server version 1.0.153. I just got the "scales" package installed version 0.5.0 . But when loading the package library(scales), I get the following error:

```
Error in [[3L]](cond):
Package 'scales' version 0.4.1 cannot be unloaded:
Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace 'scales' is imported by 
'ggplot2' so cannot be unloaded.
```

Please help me with a possible solution.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Also install the ggplot2 library in the R studio
Any don't forget to import library in the console before using it

Comment: I also have this problem with loading scales 1.0.0 as scales 0.5.0 is attached to ggplot2, but I already have ggplot2 installed and loaded (via tidyverse). Is there any other way I can fix this?